# QGIS 2.18 C++ API: How do I match the scale of vector and raster layers with different crs?

Tags: qgis, c++, qt, windows-10, standalone

I'm loading two layers to QGIS maps canvas: the first is a shapefile, with EPSG:4326 crs. The second is an xml for Goolge TileServer, with EPSG:3857 crs.

**Google TileServer - Hybrid.xml**

```
<Service name="TMS">
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Map -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Satellite -->
    <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Hybrid -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=t&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Terrain -->
    <!-- <ServerUrl>http://mt.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&amp;x=${x}&amp;y=${y}&amp;z=${z}</ServerUrl> --> <!-- Terrain, Streets and Water  -->
</Service>
<DataWindow>
    <UpperLeftX>-20037508.34</UpperLeftX>
    <UpperLeftY>20037508.34</UpperLeftY>
    <LowerRightX>20037508.34</LowerRightX>
    <LowerRightY>-20037508.34</LowerRightY>
    <TileLevel>20</TileLevel>
    <TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
    <TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
    <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:3857</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<MaxConnections>5</MaxConnections>
<Cache>
    <Depth>2</Depth>
    <Extension>.jpg</Extension>
</Cache>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

When I load both layers directly in QGIS, the scales match OK and the layers align correctly. When I load them using QGIS C++ API, they  don´t.

This is the cpp code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

// M_PI patch
#ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846
#endif

// noexcept patch
#ifndef no_except_work_around_H
#define no_except_work_around_H
#if (_MSC_VER <= 1800)
#include <xkeycheck.h>
#define noexcept
#endif
#endif //no_except_work_around_H

// QGIS Includes
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsproviderregistry.h>
#include <qgsmaplayerregistry.h>
#include <qgsvectorlayer.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>

// Globals
QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas;
QList <QgsMapCanvasLayer> myLayerSet;
QDir appDir;
QString myAppDir;
QString myPluginsDir;
QString myBaseDir;
QString appData;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    // Member initializers
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)

{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // App paths
    appDir = QApplication::applicationDirPath();
//    appDir.cdUp();
    myAppDir = appDir.absolutePath() + "/";
    myPluginsDir = myAppDir + "plugins/";
    myBaseDir = myAppDir + "base/";

    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath(myAppDir);
    QgsApplication::setPluginPath(myPluginsDir);

//  Instantiate Provider Registry
    QgsProviderRegistry::instance(myPluginsDir);
    QgsApplication::initQgis();

//     Create the Map Canvas
    mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(0, 0);
    mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
    mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
    mypMapCanvas->setCrsTransformEnabled(true);

    ui->HL1->addWidget(mypMapCanvas);

//  Add vector layer
    QgsVectorLayer * myVLayer = new QgsVectorLayer("D:/GIS/base/departamentos.shp", "Deptos", "ogr", true);
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(myVLayer, true);
    myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(myVLayer, true));
    mypMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);
    mypMapCanvas->zoomToFullExtent();

    //  Add raster layer
    QgsRasterLayer * myRLayer = new QgsRasterLayer("D:/GIS/base/Google TileServer - Satellite.xml", "Google", "gdal", true);
    QgsMapLayerRegistry::instance()->addMapLayer(myRLayer, true);
    myLayerSet.append(QgsMapCanvasLayer(myRLayer, true));
    mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
    mypMapCanvas->setLayerSet(myLayerSet);
    mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
    mypMapCanvas->refresh();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Both layers load OK but with a scale mismatch.

In QT Creator, the Application Output says:

```
c:\src\qgis\src\core\qgscoordinatereferencesystem.cpp(296) : (QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::loadFromDb) [3ms] failed : /resources/srs.db does not exist!
```

The complete log is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19350yhS24xsSmyQjUyDmRIADuS1LhLnP/view?usp=sharing).

It seems there's a path issue with **srs.db** that I can't solve, and then, the crs or the scale is not correctly set for the raster or the vector layer. I don't know how the QGIS API handles the providers' (**ogr** or **gdal**) paths.

All what I did was of no use:

- Set the GDAL_DATA environment variable to the directory where srs.db is. Now I'm using Qgis 2.18.16 API and the file is in *C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-rel-dev/resources*. Bu the way, I'm using Windows 10.
- Copy srs.db to the output directory (debug and release).
- Copy srs.db to the directory set by `QgsApplication::setPrefixPath`

Nothing worked. Any suggestion?

Where should I use `setCrsTransformEnabled(true)`?

- with `QgsMapCanvas`?
- with `QgsMapSettings`?
- with `QgsTracer`?

Answer (score 0):

Diego Sartori! I saw your problem, and I have exactly the same problem. How did you solve your problem finally?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/262357)